# Displaying a Youtube clip in python

Tags: python, ipython

I am new to python, and attempting to load a short clip in my python code.
Is there is a way on displaying a youtube (or any other url support code) clip via python command? Something like iframe tag with src of HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python

Comment: See the following link for the IPython documentation for displaying a YouTube. https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.YouTubeVideo

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your question is tagged `ipython`, and IPython does allow you to embed a YouTube video in the notebook,

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
# a talk about IPython at Sage Days at U. Washington, Seattle.
# Video credit: William Stein.
YouTubeVideo('1j_HxD4iLn8')
```

See live example here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#Video

Comment: This works locally. But when I push it to github, the video just doesn't appear. Can you share please why there is this issue? This is my notebook: https://github.com/ErfanEbrahimiBazaz/web_traffic_prediction/blob/master/1-timeseries_notebook1.ipynb

Comment: Yes, I also can not show the video while the notebook pushed to GitHub as pointed by @E.Erfan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed with IPython. 
I did not know there's a specific function to run YouTube links!
I used the embed code.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, IFrame
```

You could also not import IFrame, but it kindly suggests you import IFrame as well.
Then, you copy the "copy embed code" from the video of your choice and paste it as a string in HTML().

```
HTML('<iframe width="x" height="y" src="url" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Class for embedding a yt video in an IPython session, based on video id.

> class IPython.display.YouTubeVideo(id, width=400, height=300,
> **kwargs)

Example:

```html
<iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba%28171%2C+184%2C+195%2C+1%29&t=seti&wt=none&l=auto&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=from%2520IPython.display%2520import%2520YouTubeVideo%250A%2523%2520YouTubeVideo%28id%252C%2520with%252C%2520height%252C%2520start%2520%253D%2520start_time%29%250AYouTubeVideo%28id%2520%253D%2520%271j_HxD4iLn8%27%252C%2520width%253D400%252C%2520height%253D300%252C%2520start%2520%253D%252020%29"
  style="width: 715px; height: 242px; border:0; transform: scale(1); overflow:hidden;"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>
```